# how to using flash/flex to record video by camera without media server？

Tags: flash, apache-flex, record, flv

how to using flash/flex to record video by camera without media server？

no need media server, saved by location or browser cache, when stop record, it will upload flv file to server by http post , not media stream

Answer (score 0):

To encode an FLV to a ByteArray, start by instantiating ByteArrayFlvEncoder. The rest is similar to the last version, but you can now call updateDurationMetadata() when you’re done to update the duration property in the metadata. Finally, call kill() to prepare the object for garbage collection:
?

```
var baFlvEncoder:ByteArrayFlvEncoder = new ByteArrayFlvEncoder(myFrameRate);

baFlvEncoder.setVideoProperties(myWidth, myHeight, VideoPayloadMakerAlchemy);
// (Omit the 3rd argument to NOT use Alchemy if you're targeting Flash 9)
baFlvEncoder.setAudioProperties(BaseFlvEncoder.SAMPLERATE_44KHZ, true, false, true);

baFlvEncoder.start();

baFlvEncoder.addFrame(myBitmapData, myAudioByteArray);
baFlvEncoder.addFrame(myBitmapData, myAudioByteArray); // etc.

baFlvEncoder.updateDurationMetadata();

saveOutMyFileUsingFileReference( baFlvEncoder.byteArray );

baFlvEncoder.kill(); // for garbage collection
```

And

To encode an FLV directly to a local file (in AIR), instantiate FileStreamFlvEncoder with a File reference, and open up the exposed FileStream, and then close it when you’re all done:
?

```
var myFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("video.flv");
var fsFlvEncoder:FileStreamFlvEncoder = new FileStreamFlvEncoder(myFile, myFrameRate);
fsFlvEncoder.fileStream.openAsync(myFile, FileMode.UPDATE);

fsFlvEncoder.setVideoProperties(myWidth, myHeight, VideoPayloadMakerAlchemy);
fsFlvEncoder.setAudioProperties(BaseFlvEncoder.SAMPLERATE_44KHZ, true, false, true);

fsFlvEncoder.start();

fsFlvEncoder.addFrame(myBitmapData, myAudioByteArray);
fsFlvEncoder.addFrame(myBitmapData, myAudioByteArray); // etc.

fsFlvEncoder.updateDurationMetadata();

fsFlvEncoder.fileStream.close();

fsFlvEncoder.kill();
```

For More Detail Use Below Reference Link:

http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/updated-flv-encoder-alchem/